How to make Spiral in Geometry nodes [ but without node spiral ]
I need to make spiral in blender geometry nodes but not using spiral node any ideas how to do this?

The reason why you can't use the spiral node may affect the validity of the answer, please elaborate...

Yes, but it would be interesting to know why because it is so easy with the Curve Spiral. It sounds as if your main problem is finding the maths to do that, which makes it not a Blender problem in the first place. Having a formula but not knowing how to implement it with nodes would be more of a Blender problem. But if the maths is not your problem it would really be interesting to know why you don't want to use the dedicated node, because whatever restricts you from doing simple might affect possible solutions as well.

As You said i need to do it not in blender but in UE4 but setting can be similar

Short question - short answer.


